# Vyper: Call function in __init__, Function does not exist or has not been declared yet

Tags: constructor, vyper

I have some vyper code as such:

```py
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
# @version ^0.3.3

supply: uint256
decimals: uint256

@internal
def updateSupply(_supply: uint256):
    self.supply = _supply

@external
def __init__():
    self.decimals = 18
    self.updateSupply(1000000000000000000)
```

But on compile, I get an error:

```
vyper.exceptions.FunctionDeclarationException: Function does not exist or has not been declared yet (reminder: functions cannot call functions later in code than themselves)
  contract "MyContract.vy", function "__init__", line 34:4 
       33     self.decimals = 18
  ---> 34     self.updateSupply(1000000000000000000)
  ------------^
       35
```

Why can't I call this function inside my constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was compiling with an older version of vyper. This feature was introduced in May of 2022

https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/pull/2496

Comment: for ref: introduced in v0.3.4